# Retag option missing

Tags: support, tags, retagging

Yesterday, I was able to see the "retag" option beneath questions (and successfully retagged a question), but today I'm not seeing that option.  Anyone know why I wouldn't be seeing this option anymore?  Retag only requires 1 reputation in the beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sort of a common issue that people face in the UI as they gain more privileges. Here's some helpful information from [this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148764/155826):

> Until you hit 1000 reputation and gain the privilege to edit questions and answers, the only way you can make an edit is as a suggested edit.
>
> However, the privilege to retag questions is gained at a mere 200 reputation. Thus, for users who have between 200 and 999 reputation, they'll need to use the "edit tags" link that appears to the right of the tags.
>
> Once you hit 1000 reputation and you have full privileges to edit questions and answers, there's no need for a separate link to edit only tags, and at that point in time, you'll be able to use the edit link under the question to edit tags.
>
> In fact, between 1K and 2K reputation, the only option to edit tags is to actually edit the question. Once you hit 2K, the "edit tags" link comes back.

Keep in mind that, for the next few days, the reputation requirements are set very low. Anyone can retag a question, editing privileges are awarded at 500 reputation.

***I edited the above quoted material to reference the privilege levels in the public beta.***

Comment: Thanks for posting the specifics.  One point of clarification -- I had to look up the significance of the 2K level.  For anyone else wondering, that's the highest level, Trusted User.  Makes sense that trusted users get all functions enabled, but it's awkward that the separate retag function disappears between earning edit privs and earning Trusted User.  Also, the FAQ suggests to avoid trivial edits, and some retags may be minor.  So IMO, it would be better to keep the separate retag function after getting Edit privs, though I realize that's outside the scope of the Genealogy SE.

Comment: Hi @efgen, keep in mind that once we move to public beta, 2K means [access to moderator tools](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools). Trusted User would come at the 4K level. Privilege levels are at their very lowest during the private beta. With that said, the workflow for editing tags vs posts is a bit funky.

Comment: Sorry, I was indeed looking at the privilege list for the private beta, even though I knew better -- thanks for the correction!

Comment: @efgen: The warning to avoid trivial edits is more for users who need their edits reviewed because of the burden it places on reviewers. If you have the edit privilege, go ahead and fix those 1-character typos.

Comment: Seems that you have to get there first as well.  I was about to retag http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/help-finding-2x-grandfather-william-r-redikers-records-prior-to-1857 to add "united-states" (it was another American who thinks they're on some sort of national forum so don't mention country) but the edit and retag are greyed out, and hovering over them it says another edit has already been suggested.  So I guess I have to wait for that edit to be processed, if I can be bothered, there's no way to queue them?

Comment: @RobHoare - This will get a little easier once we all gain more rep. My suggestion is to join the [Roots Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots) and drop a link in there. GeneJ hangs out in that room a lot and has full editing privileges. I went ahead and dropped one in there on your behalf.

Answer (score 3):

Relatively new to this, but you are granted various permissions when you pass certain milestones. This includes the permission may be granted to edit questions (which allows me to re-tag).

Is it possible that once you are granted editing privileges, the retagging feature is no longer necessary; no longer appears?

Comment: Ah, you may very well be correct here.  I was assuming there would always be a separate Retag option rather than having to go into full Edit mode just for tagging.  I passed 500 rep last night, which is the level needed for Edit privs.  Can someone with more SE experience confirm that this is the case?

Comment: @efgen I did do a quick search on the meta, without success (but that was today, while the there is some testing going on. BTW, nice to meet you!

Answer (score -1):

I noticed mention on another SE that all the sites had been put into ['read only mode'](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/can-we-make-read-only-mode-text-more-visible) for a brief while. This may be why you couldn't retag. Here is a link to one of the [discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143154/site-currently-in-read-only-mode) about their fix-ups. I'm sure there're more discussions about it if you look around. I was in chat a couple days ago and everyone suddenly got kicked off. That again was because the 'big guys' were doing some migrating. Someone entered the chat and said sorry and explained what they were doing.

The 'retag' option is showing on my screen right now so it must be fixed.

Comment: No, the read-only mode isn't the issue.  The site was only read-only for a little while today while they were doing some maintenance.  I'm still not seeing the retag option.  I do see the share, edit, close and flag options currently.

Comment: Don't take this personally, but I'm going to downvote this answer since it wasn't the cause of my issue.  Downvotes on meta don't affect reputation.  And, it'll give me the Critic badge here on meta LOL ;-)  The info about yesterday's maintenance was definitely useful though, and was a good thought about why I was having this problem, so thank you for posting!

Comment: @efgen LOL, okay, thanks for the heads up.